# Unexpected output in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a Ruby on Rails step-by-step and at some step
I get a rather different output from the video in the tutorial,
even though as far as I can see my code and the tutorial's are exactly
the same.

Here is the related code (in file `app/views/projects/show.html.erb`) :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong> <%= @project.name %> </strong>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Ends at:</strong>
  <%= @project.ends_at %>
</p>

<h2>Tasks for this project </h2>

<ul>
<%= @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
<li>
<%= check_box_tag "task_done_#{task.id}", "", task.done %>
<%# <%= link_to task.title, task %> 
<%= task.title %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

Here is my output :

[image]

and the output in the tutorial video :

[image]

Why does Ruby on Rails output the task object's description ? I cannot see any place in my code where I tell it to.

Comment: Remove the `=` before `@project.tasks.each do |task|` and change `<%# <%= ` to `<%= `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `=` in this line `<%= @project.tasks.each do |task| %>`

```
<ul>
<% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
<li>
<%= check_box_tag "task_done_#{task.id}", "", task.done %>
<%# <%= link_to task.title, task %> 
<%= task.title %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

***Small Note:***

`<% %>` - *Executes the code.*

`<%= %>` - *Prints the Output.*

Comment: Thanks for answering my stupid question and for the charitable "small note"

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @sawa On what point do you say that this doesn't provide an answer?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.